# Intuitive explanation of the expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

In regards to the expected value topic an example I have read is:

> If the probability of an event happening is $\frac{1}{5000}$ and the
> payoff if it occurs is \$$200,000$ then by multiplying
> the probability with the amount that is expected to be payed out for each such occurrence happening (think of insurance policies)

I am not sure how to intuitively interpret this multiplication. I guess if the probability is $100\%$ then the payout is \$$200,000$ and if it is $50\%$ it is \$$100,000$ but seems to me kind of arbitrary/crude. Any help here?

Comment: You seem to understand it.  What do you think is "crude"??

Comment: It may help to think of it from the insurance company's point of view: they observe large numbers of events, calculate probabilities based on their observations and use that to set prices that will give them their desired profit.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Because somehow we multiply a quantity that is probability with a quantity that is an amount and that seems kind of odd since they are different sets.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an *interpretation* question, I feel free to answer,
without *work* being shown.

Go back to the original question.

Suppose that $5000$ people form a pool and agree to evenly share the proceeds.

On *average*, exactly one of the $5000$ people will *win* $\$200,000,$ while
everyone else wins *nothing*.

This money will then be evenly divided by everyone in the pool.

Each person will therefore get $\frac{\$200,000}{5000}.$

This represents each person's expected value.

---

Intuitively, the same result can be computed by assuming that 1 person, operating alone, enters a contest $5000$ times.  Since he expects to win, *on average*, once out of every $5000$ times, he expects to win once.

This means that as a result of his entering the contest $5000$ times, *on average*, he (somewhere along the way) wins the contest exactly once, receiving $\$200,000.$

This means that his *expectation* is that it takes $5000$ occurrences to win $\$200,000.$  Therefore, his expectation is that his *average* win, for each occurrence is

$\frac{\$200,000}{5000}.$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the two comment/questions of Jim:

> In your first example I think that is equivalent to stating that the company pays out $200,000 for every 5,000 customers...

Yes, I agree.

> from whom it received $5,000 \times \$50 = \$250,000.$ Hence the profit is $\$50,000$ for the company which means $\$10$ per customer.

First of all, nowhere in your original question is there any mention of customers paying $\$50$ for a *policy*.  However, taking this **added constraint** at face value, I completely agree with your math.  That is, the company's expected profit per customer is

$$\frac{(\$50 \times 5000) - (\$200,000)}{5,000 ~\text{customers}} = 
\frac{\$50,000}{5,000 ~\text{customers}}
= \frac{\$10}{1 ~\text{customer}}.
$$

> Somehow the way you describe it I can not directly understand it except how I interpreted it, because each person in your example literary will not get $\$40$ so it can't be the expected value. The company can expect to get $\$10$ per person and that would be the actual expected value. Am I confused here?

My original answer reflected in effect that there was no stated cost for the *prize*, which in the insurance company analogy, translates into **free insurance policies**.  Once you **add the constraint** that each policy *costs* $\$50$, then **yes**, each customer's expectation is *reduced* by $\$50$.

This means that each *customer's* expectation changes from $\$(+40)$ to $\$(-10)$, which exactly corresponds to the insurance company's profit of $\dfrac{\$10}{1 ~\text{customer}}$.

> In your second analogy, I think you mean that either we state the person wins $\$200,000$ once or $\$40$ per participation on average are equivalent definitions. Isn't the cost of $\$50$ per participation required to be included in the second analogy?

Yes, the cost of $\$50$ per participation is required to be included.  However, in my original answer, I could **not** include it, because in the original problem there was no specified *cost per participation*.

Comment: In your first example I think that is equivalent to stating that the company pays out $\$200,000$ for every $5,000$ customers from whom it received $5,000 \cdot \$50 = \$250,000$. Hence the profit is $\$50,000$ for the company which means $\$10$ per customer. Somehow the way you describe it I can not directly understand it except how I interpreted it, because each person in your example literary will not get $\$40$ so it can't be the expected value. The company can expect to get $\$10$ per person and that would be the actual expected value. Am I confused here?

Comment: In your second analogy, I think you mean that either we state the person wins $\$200,000$ once or $\$40$ per participation on average are equivalent definitions. Isn't the cost of $\$50$ per participation required to be included in the second analogy?

Comment: @Jim See the Addendum that I just added to my answer.